# Was fascism ever philosophically appealing?

Tags: political-philosophy

I remember reading, in better times about a decade ago, the fascism article in a philosophy encyclopedia. It summarily introduced the main ideas, and then dismissed them as *utterly* invalidated by their actual existence etc.

Was there ever any doubt that fascism was not an attractive political philosophy?

If not, then why: i.e. what can be pointed to in fascist political philosophy which cannot or just *should not* work?

Comment: It is not hard to see that Fascism is, in motivation, Plato minus Communism, so it is as tenable as Plato, or can be seen as a logical step toward Plato's Republic that is compatible with Capitalism.  But it arose, at least in name, too late to be looking that far back.

Comment: Are we talking about Mussolini's definition of facism? People use that word a lot now to mean stuff that it didnt necessarily mean initially.

Comment: I take it that fascism as a political ideology was attractive fascists; this is just a tautology, but this is why tautologies can be useful.

Comment: Fascism was appealing to lots of people, e.g. - many people in the administration of Franklin Delano Roosevelt expressed admiration for Mussolini. Also fascism is not compatible with capitalism http://www.econlib.org/library/Enc/Fascism.html

Comment: jobermark, the suggestion that "Fascism is Plato minus Communisim" is pretty controversial. Certainly Popper and others have argued as much. But in recent decades, that way of interpreting of Plato has been in decline. To begin with it neglects the conclusions reached in The Statesman that all actual rulers are sophists of various degrees rather than true statesmen.

Comment: Perhaps of interest to you would be the philosophy of Thomas Carlyle, whose philosophy is often considered as a prelude to fascism. See for example [this article](https://fee.org/articles/the-founding-father-of-fascism/).

Answer (score 2):

Emmanuel Levinas took Nazism seriously enough to pen a very astute rebuttal. See his 1934 essay Reflections on the Philosophy of Hitlerism (reprinted in Unforeseen History).

Some argue that the vast majority of Heidegger's political writings are little more than regurgitated Nazism. Certainly German and Italian intellectuals at the time drew deeply on Heidegger's writings. The literature on whether or not one can separate Heidegger's Nazism from his philosophy is a vast and deep pool.

Lastly, "state of exception" theorists like Carl Schmitt and Giorgio Agamben argue for something very similar to Mussolini's Fascism.

Comment: 'Fun'-fact: Carl Schmitt (philosopher of law, the first one who thought about constitutional law as a destinct topic of political philosophy) was wild with excitement seeing his political theory finally confirmed by Hilter's Ermächtigungsgesetz (Enabling Act) of 1933 and expressed his delight in various occasions. At this point, fascism was definitely appealing to him. He had to observe in horror where it lead, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Machiavelli urged that the monarch must rule using fascist authority because it was the responsibility by birthright. He goes on to explain that it is a necessity that benefits the people, as they are meant to be ruled, given the dialectical relationship between ruler and vassals. Hegel describes a similar relationship which he identifies as the "Master and Slave" relationship (though Hegel discusses it metaphysically, while Machiavelli believes its Divine Ascription and therefore a literal application).

Comment: i meant something more specific than absolute authority

Comment: I'm unsure the difference. Could you clarify?

Comment: hmm well i'm not well versed but it isn't just a dictatorship, else its not different to all of them

Comment: Ok, I see now. I'll edit or delete shortly.